# Find the global minimum in 2 dimensions with boundary conditions

Tags: calculus

I just have been introduced into derivation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in university and tried to find the minimum/maximum of a function.

I started with the following function:

$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 2y + 2$$

The Jacobian is:

$$J_f=\left[\begin{matrix}
    2(x-1) & 2(y+1)
    \end{matrix}\right]$$

It's easy to see that at $(1,-1)$ needs to be a local minima or maxima. Without showing the Hesse-Matrix, we can probably agree on the fact that there is a local minima.

Obviously the function diverges if $x$ or $y$ goes towards infinity.

Therefor I tried to set myself a challenge and find the maximum point for every $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$ (a circle with area 2)

---

This is my attempt for finding the maximum value on the boundary:

Every point on the boundary will be expressed in polar-coordinates

$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 2y + 2$$

$$x = 2 \cdot cos(\phi)$$
$$y = 2 \cdot sin(\phi)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\phi) = (2 \cdot cos(\phi))^2 + (2 \cdot sin(\phi))^2 - 2(2 \cdot cos(\phi)) + 2(2 \cdot sin(\phi)) + 2$$
$$f(\phi) = 4 \cdot cos(\phi)^2 + 4 \cdot sin(\phi)^2 - 4 \cdot cos(\phi)) + 4 \cdot sin(\phi)) + 2$$
$$f(\phi) = 4 - 4 \cdot cos(\phi)) + 4 \cdot sin(\phi)) + 2$$

Now I can find the maximum on the boundary because I converted it to a one dimensional problem by taking the derivative and so on.

I've never done something like this and my question is:

> How could this have been done faster or better and for any boundary? Assuming that my boundary would have been $x+y = 2$, my attempt would not really have worked.

Comment: Look up Lagrange multiplier method

Comment: And your approach should work for $x+y=2$. Substitute $x=t$ and $y=2-t$ in $f(x,y)$ and you get a manageable function to derive.

Comment: @Ernie060 yeah you are right with that. But I messed up at that point because I actually meant |x| + |y| < 2